# Cpanel and Command line are different from each other for PHP version

Tags: php, linux, command-line, version, cpanel

I need to switch Php version from 5.4 to 5.5. I adjusted Php version in Cpanel. Now current version seems 5.5 in Cpanel. However, I can't see a change when I execute this command from command pompt:

```
php -v
```

This is output of it:

```
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) ...
```

How can I switch Php version for Command line?

Comment: Must be a problem. Usually cpanel has one PHP for Apache and other for internal use. `/usr/local/bin/php -v``/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php -v` Only if you uses Easyapache 4 can use multiple versions of PHP. Try `php -i |grep -i configuration` (on user shell) for see that version use.

Comment: The internal php for cpanel will not have any effect on `php -v` command's responds. You will have to explicitly/manually change the default php into the internal one.

Answer (score 3):

For those who have these problem with any PHP version, you can create a symbolic link to the php version you want and edit the PATH to prioritize your command per user:

```
> mkdir bin
> ln -s /usr/local/bin/ea-php73 bin/php
> vim .bashrc

#Put the following code on bottom
export PATH="/home/[usuario]/bin:$PATH"
```

Logout, login and try `php -v`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using this:
/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update

I'm using Cpanel & WHM v96.0.15

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. `cpanel` comes with a script called `easyapache`. You can find the script under

> `/scripts/easyapache`

. Its an interactive script will let you choose versions on the go.

Comment: For know version of PHP not need use easyapache.

Comment: For new version of php you can install it through anyway but if your machine is depended on cPanel. It is highly recommended to use cPanel utilities to upgrade. I have seen things break. A lot.

Comment: I can't find Easyapache under scripts Also I have shared hosting. For this reason I can't find it?

Comment: Yes, It requires root privilege.

Comment: Actually I want to install composer, so I have Php version problem. Another way to change Php version?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the php version using EasyApache4 and MultiPHP (that would be one way to do it).

Another way would be to have CloudLinux license, install Cloudlinux kernel and CageFS + PHPSelector. This way each cPanel user can have its own custom php version no matter what php version runs on the server (You can change the php version from cPanel, from 5.x to 7.x). Of course, for isntalling composer you will need to provide ssh access to that user.

You can run EasyApache as root on a ssh console or via WHM. If you just have a cPanel account and not root access you won't be able to change the PHP version. Even if you change it you cant installer composer without ssh access.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple solution would be to use cPanel web Terminal.